# Perl printing hashref values

Tags: perl

I cant seem to print values of hashref.

I can print keys as such:

```
 foreach (sort keys %$wss_href) {
     print "$_\n";
 }
```

I would like to print the values as well for each key:
so i tried:

```
 print "$_ => $wss_href{$_}\n";
 print "$_ => $%$wss_href{$_}\n";
```

and it keeps giving me an error `Global symbol "%wss_href" requires explicit package name`

how do i deference hashref to get the values for each key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's `%NAME` for a hash, it's `%{REF}` for a hash reference.

If it's `$NAME{EXPR}` for a hash, it's `${REF}{EXPR}` for a hash reference.

See the pattern?

You're looking for the following:

```
for (sort keys %{ $wss_href }) {
    print "$_ => ${ $wss_href }{$_}\n";
}
```

The curlies can be omitted if the reference expression is just a variable.

```
for (sort keys %$wss_href) {
    print "$_ => $$wss_href{$_}\n";
}
```

But there's a cleaner syntax you can also use.

```
for (sort keys %$wss_href) {
    print "$_ => $wss_href->{$_}\n";
}
```

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: `perllol` is by far the best perl document I've ever read. `perlreftut` is nice too. The others are a wee bit dry. Thanks for the perl monks link.

Answer (score 4):

You need arrow syntax: `$wss_href->{$_}`.

The difference between `$x{k}` and `$x->{k}` is similar to the difference between `x.k` and `x->k` in C.

Answer (score 3):

To deference a value in a hashref, use `$wss_href->{$_};`